# Copy map values to vector in STL

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Working my way through Effective STL at the moment. Item 5 suggests that it's usually preferable to use range member functions to their single element counterparts. I currently wish to copy all the values in a map (i.e. - I don't need the keys) to a vector.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: If the keys are not needed, the whole map might not be needed as well. In such case consider moving the values from the map to the vector as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42282382/8805602).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can't easily use a range here because the iterator you get from a map refers to a std::pair, where the iterators you would use to insert into a vector refers to an object of the type stored in the vector, which is (if you are discarding the key) not a pair.

I really don't think it gets much cleaner than the obvious:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    typedef map <string, int> MapType;
    MapType m;  
    vector <int> v;

    // populate map somehow

    for( MapType::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it ) {
        v.push_back( it->second );
    }
}
```

which I would probably re-write as a template function if I was going to use it more than once. Something like:

```
template <typename M, typename V> 
void MapToVec( const  M & m, V & v ) {
    for( typename M::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it ) {
        v.push_back( it->second );
    }
}
```

Comment: Python has truly spoiled me :-(

Comment: Nice, the template.  Maybe give it an output iterator instead of a container!

Comment: Skurmedel's solution is even nicer: use the 'transform' function with a p -> p.second functor.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in Occam's Razor - don't introduce entities unecessarily. In the case of the transform solution, we need a subsidiary function which is not needed on the explicit loop solution. So until we get nameless functions, I'll stick with my solution.

Comment: Beware of Occam's Razor interpretation. Introducing a new non-const variable "it" may not the safest solution in the end. STL algorithms have been proven fast and robust for quite some time now.

Comment: But as soon as lambda functions are there, it will be the simplest solution.

Comment: @vincent but the scope of the variable is limited to the function - if I could limit the scope of the subsidiary function (as I will be able to, eventually) then I would use the transform approach myself - until then, not.

Comment: @tstenner - unfortunately, we have to program in the here and now.

Comment: @neil Actually, you could use an anonymous namespace in order to hide the functors from the outside world.

Comment: With C++11, there is now a more elegant solution with range-based for. See @Seth's answer. But also the traditional approach with iterator leaves room form improvement: `m.end()` does not change during the loop. You should cache it in a variable.

Comment: @GiladNaor, the first option here is rather pythonic:
http://www.techiedelight.com/convert-map-vector-key-value-pairs-cpp/

Comment: Excuse me, doesn't `++it` in the for loop mean that the code skips the first element in the map `m`, and at the end attempts to access `m.end()->second`?

Comment: why do you not use reserve?

Answer (score 73):

You could probably use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for that purpose. I would maybe prefer Neils version though, depending on what is more readable.

---

Example by [xtofl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6610/xtofl) (see comments):

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template< typename tPair >
struct second_t {
    typename tPair::second_type operator()( const tPair& p ) const { return p.second; }
};

template< typename tMap > 
second_t< typename tMap::value_type > second( const tMap& m ) { return second_t< typename tMap::value_type >(); }


int main() {
    std::map<int,bool> m;
    m[0]=true;
    m[1]=false;
    //...
    std::vector<bool> v;
    std::transform( m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter( v ), second(m) );
    std::transform( m.begin(), m.end(), std::ostream_iterator<bool>( std::cout, ";" ), second(m) );
}
```

Very generic, remember to give him credit if you find it useful.

Comment: I would suggest to use lambda for the last parameter.

Comment: @varepsilon: Probably a good idea (if one is on a modern C++ compiler), but I'm not that confident with C++ anymore, I'm kinda a C dude these days. If anyone wants to improve it and thinks they can do it, please go ahead :)

Answer (score 48):

With C++11 we have the fancy new `for` loop:

```
for (const auto &s : schemas)
   names.push_back(s.second);
```

where `schemas` is a `std::map` and `names` is an `std::vector`.

This populates the array (`names`) with values from the map (`schemas`); change `s.second` to `s.first` to get an array of keys.

Comment: Shortest and cleanest solution. And probably the fastest (tested to be faster than the accepted solution and also faster than @Aragornx's solution). Add `reserve()` and you'll get another performance gain. With the advent of C++11 that should now be the accepted solution!

Comment: Agree, this is the most clear, simple and self explaining solution (with reserve()). Algorithms, lambdas etc. here is an overkill (killing a fly with hammer...).

Answer (score 38):

```
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter
std::transform( 
    your_map.begin(), 
    your_map.end(),
    std::back_inserter(your_values_vector),
    [](auto &kv){ return kv.second;} 
);
```

Sorry that I didn't add any explanation - I thought that code is so simple that is doesn't require any explanation.
So:

```
transform( beginInputRange, endInputRange, outputIterator, unaryOperation)
```

this function calls `unaryOperation` on every item from `inputIterator` range (`beginInputRange`-`endInputRange`). The value of operation is stored into `outputIterator`.

If we want to operate through whole map - we use map.begin() and map.end() as our input range. We want to store our map values into vector - so we have to     use back_inserter on our vector: `back_inserter(your_values_vector)`. The back_inserter is special outputIterator that pushes new elements at the end of given (as paremeter) collection.
The last parameter is unaryOperation - it takes only one parameter - inputIterator's value. So we can use lambda:
`[](auto &kv) { [...] }`, where &kv is just a reference to map item's pair. So if we want to return only values of map's items we can simply return kv.second:

```
[](auto &kv) { return kv.second; }
```

I think this explains any doubts.

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Yes! this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I think this only works starting from C++14, since auto isn't supported in lambda's prior to that.
Explicit function signature would still work.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org), you can use boost::bind to access the second value of the pair as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int main()
{
   typedef std::map<std::string, int> MapT;
   typedef std::vector<int> VecT;
   MapT map;
   VecT vec;

   map["one"] = 1;
   map["two"] = 2;
   map["three"] = 3;
   map["four"] = 4;
   map["five"] = 5;

   std::transform( map.begin(), map.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(vec),
                   boost::bind(&MapT::value_type::second,_1) );
}
```

This solution is based on a post from Michael Goldshteyn on the [boost mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2006/01/99760.php).

Answer (score 20):

Using lambdas one can perform the following:

```
{
   std::map<std::string,int> m;
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.reserve(m.size());
   std::for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),
                 [&v](const std::map<std::string,int>::value_type& p) 
                 { v.push_back(p.second); });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to v.reserve(m.size()) because v will grow as you push_back new elements.

Comment: @DraganOstojić .reserve() only causes one reallocation.  Depending on the number of elements, .push_back() may perform multiple allocations to get to the same size.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I would do.
Also I would use a template function to make the construction of select2nd easier.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

/*
 * A class to extract the second part of a pair
 */   
template<typename T>
struct select2nd
{
    typename T::second_type operator()(T const& value) const
    {return value.second;}
};

/*
 * A utility template function to make the use of select2nd easy.
 * Pass a map and it automatically creates a select2nd that utilizes the
 * value type. This works nicely as the template functions can deduce the
 * template parameters based on the function parameters. 
 */
template<typename T>
select2nd<typename T::value_type> make_select2nd(T const& m)
{
    return select2nd<typename T::value_type>();
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int,std::string>   m;
    std::vector<std::string>    v;

    /*
     * Please note: You must use std::back_inserter()
     *              As transform assumes the second range is as large as the first.
     *              Alternatively you could pre-populate the vector.
     *
     * Use make_select2nd() to make the function look nice.
     * Alternatively you could use:
     *    select2nd<std::map<int,std::string>::value_type>()
     */   
    std::transform(m.begin(),m.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(v),
                   make_select2nd(m)
                  );
}
```

Comment: Good one. And why make_select2nd are not in the stl?

Comment: select2nd is an extension to the STL in the SGI version (so unofficial). Adding function templates as utilities is just second nature now (see make_pair<>() for inspiration).

Answer (score 2):

One way  is to use functor:

```
 template <class T1, class T2>
    class CopyMapToVec
    {
    public: 
        CopyMapToVec(std::vector<T2>& aVec): mVec(aVec){}

        bool operator () (const std::pair<T1,T2>& mapVal) const
        {
            mVec.push_back(mapVal.second);
            return true;
        }
    private:
        std::vector<T2>& mVec;
    };


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> myMap;
    myMap["test1"] = 1;
    myMap["test2"] = 2;

    std::vector<int>  myVector;

    //reserve the memory for vector
    myVector.reserve(myMap.size());
    //create the functor
    CopyMapToVec<std::string, int> aConverter(myVector);

    //call the functor
    std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), aConverter);
}
```

Comment: I would not bother with the variable aConverter. just create a temporary in the for_each. std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), CopyMapToVec<std::string, int>(myVector));

Comment: prefer 'transform', since that's what you're doing: transforming a map into a vector using a quite straightforward functor.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it should be

```
std::transform( map.begin(), map.end(), 
                   std::back_inserter(vec), 
                   boost::bind(&MapT::value_type::first,_1) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
std::vector<V> MapValuesAsVector(const std::map<K, V>& map)
{
   std::vector<V> vec;
   vec.reserve(map.size());
   std::for_each(std::begin(map), std::end(map),
        [&vec] (const std::map<K, V>::value_type& entry) 
        {
            vec.push_back(entry.second);
        });
    return vec;
}
```

usage:

auto vec = MapValuesAsVector(anymap);

Comment: I think your _vec_ will be twice size of _map_

Comment: thanks dyomas, I've updated the function to do a reserve instead of resize and now it works correctly

Answer (score 2):

We should use the transform function from STL algorithm, the last parameter of transform function could be a function object, function pointer or a lambda function that convert item of map to item of vector. This case map have items have type pair that need to convert to item that has int type for vector. Here is my solution that I use lambda function:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::transform
#include <iterator>  // for back_inserted

// Map of pair <int, string> need to convert to vector of string
std::map<int, std::string> mapExp = { {1, "first"}, {2, "second"}, {3, "third"}, {4,"fourth"} };

// vector of string to store the value type of map
std::vector<std::string> vValue;

// Convert function
std::transform(mapExp.begin(), mapExp.end(), std::back_inserter(vValue),
       [](const std::pair<int, string> &mapItem)
       {
         return mapItem.second;
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers mention [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), and semantically it's the right choice. But in practice [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) might fit better for this task, because:

- it allows adding **const** to the resulting vector;
- it just looks nicer, truly functional-style.

Example (using C++17 syntax):

```
#include <numeric> // for std::accumulate. Note that it's not in <algorithm> where std::transform is located, thanks to Anton Krug for pointing this out

auto map = std::map<int,bool>{};
map[0]=true;
map[1]=false;

const auto mapValues = std::accumulate(map.begin(), map.end(), std::vector<bool>(map.size()), [](auto& vector, const auto& mapEntry) {
    vector.push_back(mapEntry.second);
    return vector;
});
```

Comment: That is not fully correct, your code wouldn't compile, here is compiling version: https://godbolt.org/z/hMafr6jzE BTW accumulate is in the <numeric> and not in the <algorithm>. The transform is in the <algorithm> so this is giving misleading information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Answer (score -3):

Surprised nobody has mentioned [the most obvious solution](http://www.techiedelight.com/convert-map-vector-key-value-pairs-cpp/), use the std::vector constructor.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
std::vector<std::pair<K,V>> mapToVector(const std::unordered_map<K,V> &map)
{
    return std::vector<std::pair<K,V>>(map.begin(), map.end());
}
```

Comment: That's because your solution does not fit the question. The vector should consist of only the values.