# Getting a list of values from a map

Tags: c++, list, stl, dictionary

Is there an stl way to get a list of values from a map?

i.e, I have:

```
std::map<A,B> myMap;
```

and I would like a function that will return just the list of values, i.e, `std::list<B>` (or set for that matter.
Is there a built-in stl way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Copy map values to vector in STL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771453/copy-map-values-to-vector-in-stl)

Comment: Not agreeing with the dup because IMO the accepted answer there is not what I would consider to be the best design choice.

Comment: Actually, this does not change the fact of this question being a duplicate, it merely means that you should answer the first question rather than the second to avoid scattering answers all over SO. I do like your answer here though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `map` element is defined as a `map::value_type`, and the type of it is a `pair<A,B>`.  `first` is the key and `second` is the value.  You can write a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) to extract  `second` from a `value_type`, and copy that in to a `vector` (or a `list`, or whatever you want.)  The best way to do the copying is to use `transform`, which does just what its name implies:  it takes a value of one type and transforms it to a different type of value.

Here's a complete working example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef map<unsigned, string> MyMap;
MyMap my_map;

struct get_second : public std::unary_function<MyMap::value_type, string>
{
    string operator()(const MyMap::value_type& value) const
    {
        return value.second;
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_map[1] = "one";
    my_map[2] = "two";
    my_map[3] = "three";
    my_map[4] = "four";
    my_map[5] = "five";

    // get a vector of values
    vector<string> my_vals;
    transform(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), back_inserter(my_vals), get_second() );

    // dump the list
    copy( my_vals.begin(), my_vals.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

### EDIT:

If you have a compiler that supports C++0x [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), you can eliminate the functor entirely.  This is very useful for making code more readable and, arguable, easier to maintain since you don't end up with dozens of little one-off functors floating around in your codebase.  Here's how you would change the code above to use a lambda:

```
transform(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), back_inserter(my_vals), [](const MyMap::value_type& val){return val.second;} );
```

Comment: Even more succinct:
transform(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), back_inserter(my_vals), [](const auto& val){return val.second;} );

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built in, no. It's simple enough to write your own function, though: Iterate over the map. The iterator will give you a `pair<A, B>`. Add each `second` value to the result list.

Comment: I would consider  `transform` and the idea of functors to be more or less built-in

Comment: @John. by saying "built in," I interpret the question to request [PHP's `array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) or [Perl's `values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) — the library provides a function tailored exactly to the task, rather than just a bunch of pieces that you have to put together to write a `values` function of your own. Things are worse if your compiler or library doesn't provide all the best pieces (like `select2nd` or lambdas).

Answer (score 3):

You can't just "get" such a list because there is no pre-existing list stored anywhere in the guts, but you can build one:

```
typedef std::map<A,B> myMapType;
myMapType myMap;
std::list<B> valueList;
for (myMapType::const_iterator it=myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); ++it) {
  valueList.push_back( it->second );
}
```

Or if you really like the more STL way:

```
class GetSecond {
  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  const T2& operator()( const std::pair<T1,T2>& key_val ) const
    { return key_val.second; }
};

typedef std::map<A,B> myMapType;
myMapType myMap;
std::list<B> valueList;
std::transform(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::back_inserter(valueList),
               GetSecond());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `select2nd` in the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed too late.  I'm about to stop bothering with the darn SGI "documentation".

Answer (score 2):

One of many "built-in" ways is of course the most obvious one. Just iterate over all pair elements, which are ordered by key (`pair::first`), and add the value (`pair::second`) to a new container, which you can construct with the correct capacity to get rid of excess allocations during the iteration and adding.

Just a note: `std::list` is seldom the container you actually want to be using. Unless, of course, you really, really **do** need its specific features.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
std::list<B> list;
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [&](const std::pair<const A, B>& ref) {
    list.push_back(ref.second);
});
```

If you don't have a C++0x compiler, first you have my sympathies, and second, you will need to build a quick function object for this purpose.

Comment: Where's the `std::transform` love?

Comment: @DeadMG:  lambdas are beyond the domain because this question isn't tagged [c++0x]

Comment: @DeadMG:  Nonetheless, I will ammend my answer to include a lamda example

Comment: @John Dibling: Lambda support stopped having to be explicitly tagged when MSVC10 and GCC4.5 both support them.

Comment: @DeadMG:  Really?  Even though C++ and C++0x are not the same?

Comment: @DeadMG: I disagree. Like it or not, many C++ programmers are not already using the latest and best compilers on the most popular OSes, because of legacy code, business decisions, and/or coding standards that do not yet allow using the new unofficial features for more portability.

Comment: @John: Yes. I expect that plenty of people are using a lambda-supporting compiler. @aschepler: That's true. But I'm hardly using some feature or library that's totally untranslatable to C++03, like perfect forwarding. It's just slightly less convenient. It's not like you can't make this answer work in C++03 without a ton of effort.

Comment: @DeadMG:  Because at the end of the day, since C++0x isn't even official yet, C++ and C++0x are *different languages*, and by your logic one might conclude that is a question is tagged only [c] it is reasonable to answer with C++ constructs.  Maybe a bit extreme, but I trust you get my point.

Comment: @John: No, I don't get your point. C++ and C are radically different languages. C++03 and C++0x are not radically different languages- they're exceedingly similar and especially in the area which my answer concerned, it is trivial to convert to C++03. Should we ask people whether they mean C++ or C when they ask if `++a++a++=a` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost's `transform_iterator`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html

```
struct GetSecond {
  template <typename K, typename T>
  const T& operator()(const std::pair<K, T> & p) const { return p.second; }
  template <typename K, typename T>
  T& operator()(std::pair<K, T> & p) const { return p.second; }
};

template <typename MapType>
  auto begin_values(MapType& m) -> decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator(m.begin(), GetSecond())) {
  return boost::make_transform_iterator(m.begin(), GetSecond());
}

template <typename MapType>
  auto end_values(MapType& m) -> decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator(m.end(), GetSecond())) {
  return boost::make_transform_iterator(m.end(), GetSecond());
}

template <typename MapType>
  struct MapValues {
  MapType & m;
  MapValues(MapType & m) : m(m) {}
  typedef decltype(begin_values(m)) iterator;
  iterator begin() { return begin_values(m); }
  iterator end() { return end_values(m); }
};

template <typename MapType>
  MapValues<MapType> get_values(MapType & m) {
  return MapValues<MapType>(m);
}


int main() {
  std::map<int, double> m;
  m[0] = 1.0;
  m[10] = 2.0;
  for (auto& x : get_values(m)) {
    std::cout << x << ',';
    x += 1;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  const std::map<int, double> mm = m;
  for (auto& x : get_values(mm)) {
    std::cout << x << ',';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```