# std::bind with type alias

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to copy the values of a `map` to a `vector` using `std::transform`. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608336/2052998) answer, I managed to to so. While searching for the way to do it, I learned about `select2nd`. So I tried to implement a "select2nd-like" operation using `std::bind`. However, when defining a `select2nd` alias, I get:

```
test.cpp:9:19: error: expected type-specifier
 using select2nd = std::bind(&T::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1);
                   ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:29:64: error: ‘select2nd’ was not declared in this scope
     std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), select2nd);
```

This is the snippet that I've come up with:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using select2nd = std::bind(&T::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1);

using std::placeholders::_1;

void printn(int i) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    std::vector<int> v1, v2;

    for (auto &i : { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }) {
        m[i] = rand();
    }

    // Works
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v1),
            std::bind(&std::map<int, int>::value_type::second, _1));
    // Doesn't
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), select2nd);

    std::for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::bind(printn, _1));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::for_each(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::bind(printn, _1));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first `transform` work, but not the second? How can I parameterize an alias to `std::bind`?

Comment: `std::bind(whatever)` is a value, not a type. If you need its type, you can use `decltype(std::bind(whatever))`. OTOH `&T::value_type::second` is a type, not  value. If you need a value, you can use `std::declval<&T::value_type::second>()`.

Comment: Nice catch! Hadn't noticed that I was binding a type to a value. Thanks! It still doesn't work, though. With `std::declval`, I get a `no matching function for call to 'declval'`. Without it, a `no matching constructor for initialization of 'select2nd<std::map<int, int>>`

Comment: `for (const auto& p : m) v.push_back(p.second);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, but not nicer:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(std::bind(&T::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1)) select2nd(T m) {
    return std::bind(&T::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1);
}

// ....

std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), select2nd(m));

// ....
```

Here is another alternative, without requiring an argument:

```
template <typename T>
    decltype(std::bind(&T::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1)) select2nd() {
        return std::bind(&T::value_type::second, std::placeholders::_1);
    }
```

You can use this like:

```
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), 
                                select2nd<std::map<int, int>>());
```

or:

```
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), 
                                select2nd<decltype(m)>());
```

Comment: As `m` is unused in `select2nd`, you may remove it and call it `select2nd<decltype(m)>()`.

Comment: Yes, but the deduction version looks clearer, does it have any runtime overhead?

Comment: Thanks! It does work, however, is there any way to not make it depend on m?

Comment: Here's where C++14 automatic return type deduction can shine (if C++14 is allowed).

Comment: @perreal: I expected no overhead with a minimum of optimization.