# Copy map keys to vector in STL using transform

Tags: c++, vector, stl

How to copy keys from map to vector. Specifically I have a `map<int, int>` and I want `keys` of the map to form a new vector (`vector<int>`).

So a map `(<1,100>; <2,99>)` should give a vector of `(1,2)`.

Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771453/copy-map-values-to-vector-in-stl), describes exactly what I need but for values, but the response is too cryptic to understand. I cannot understand how the unary operator function is written. Can somebody explain how it is written?

Comment: the unary operator:    std::transform( map.begin(), map.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(vec),
                   boost::bind(&MapT::value_type::second,_1) ); takes value associated with each entry from map and binds to the first argument of back_inserter method. in your case you'd use value_type::first

Answer (score 3):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/771463/434551) of the question you linked to in your post has almost everything you need. You need to change just one line:

Instead of

```
v.push_back( it->second );
```

use

```
v.push_back( it->first);
```

**Update, in response to OP's comments**

You can use `std::transform` with a lambda function to extract the keys of a `std::map` and put them in a `std::vector`.

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   map<int, int> m{{1, 20}, {2, 40}};
   vector<int> keys;

   // Retrieve all keys
   transform(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(keys), [](std::pair<int, int> p) { return p.first;} );

   // Dump all keys
   copy(keys.begin(), keys.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: I want to do it with `transform`