# What is the best way to get values of a map as a vector?

Tags: c++

I need to satisfy an api function that requires a vector:

```
void api_function(std::vector<int> vec);
```

For another reason, I keep values in a

```
std::map<int,int> map;
```

Now I need to pass the values of this map to the api_function.

Is there a way to do that without too much space and time overhead, i.e. without iterating through all values or creating a new vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. A vector stores its elements contiguously, and the map does not, and so there's no way to create a contiguous arrangement of ints without iterating and copying.

(General algorithms don't operate on containers for that reason, but rather on a more flexible interface like iterators, so that they don't force the user to provide a particular implementation of a range.)

Comment: True: Unfortunately I need to use that api and it isnt abstracted to use iterators. But thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a simple range loop on the map and pushing each value into a vector and then passing that to your function.

Like this:

```
for (const auto& pair : map)
    vector.push_back(pair.second);
```

Answer (score 2):

If a function asks for vector you are bound to give it a vector. At most, this will help you [Copy map values to vector in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771453/copy-map-values-to-vector-in-stl).

Answer (score 1):

As kerrek SB has stated the answer is **no**. You will need to iterate through your map.

You can do the following to add values to a dynamic vector container. Iterate through the map using [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). In this way you're not using a true iterator:

```
std::vector<int> vec;

for (std::pair<int, int>& e : map) {
   vec.push_back(e.second);
}  

...
...
api_function(vec);  // Invoke function
```

Finally you can just call your function from your API with your vector.

This will yield a computational **time and space complexity of O(n)** (with "n" being the **number of values** you have contained in your **map**).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a map implementation that uses sorted vector internally ('dense map').

Comment: No, it is not part of std, so you have to rely on third-party implementations or write your own.