# How to sort a map in OMNeT++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I didn't find any documentation about map in OMNeT++.
I'm trying to sort a `map<int,double>` by value, not by key, and erase some data.

I declare the map and iterator like this

```
std::map<int,double> Dlist;
std::map<int,double>::iterator it;
```

I tried

`sort(Dlist.begin(), Dlist.end());`

but there is an error.

Also the iterator doesn't return values

```
iterator.first
iterator.second
```

Comment: This is a purely C++ programming question. It has, just like `std::map`, nothing to do with OMNeT++. Not to mention that sorting by value does not make any sense on a data structure like `std::map`.

Comment: thank you for you answer @ Attila ,All scenario is already done , an RSU receive wsm messages and store wsm Data (has an int type)  on a map , I need to sort this map bye the value of data , I tried the code above but no result .

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is a pure C++ related problem, since you are using `std::map`.

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts a container in place, therefore there is no iterator which you can access. Additionally, in the given code the declared iterator is not even used.

Secondly, I strongly doubt that you actually want to sort the map's values. Although this is technically possible, it makes no sense: [Sorting std::map using value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value).

Instead you could copy all values from the map into a `std::vector` and then sort that vector. See [Copy map values to vector in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771453/copy-map-values-to-vector-in-stl).